# Examples of substitution and elimination reactions

Tags: organic-chemistry

What would be the major product of 4-chloro-1 pentanol reacting with water? Would cyclization occur? Would this be a type of substitution or elimination reaction?

[image]

Comment: Are you using an acid as well?

Comment: In just water? No reaction. Introduce base then you'll get cyclisation to the tetrahydrofuran see https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jo00795a026#